# Sendmail relay out of Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, sendmail, smtp

I have a site running on CentOS 5.4 through Amazon EC2. Unfortunately, Amazon has had nothing but trouble with their entire IP range getting black listed from spam tracking services regularly. I need a mail server, so I setup an smtp server elsewhere that I want to send to, but I can't just send directly to it through PHP because the direct smtp request is way too slow. What I want to do is relay through sendmail, but I've never used sendmail before, so I have no idea how to configure it. All I want is for all emails sent from localhost to be relayed to one specific external server, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to find a tutorial online, but couldn't find anything that was particularly clear as to how I go about doing that. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sendmail feature you need to configure is mailertable. Here are simple config instructions after a base install of Sendmail.

Mailertable: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-sendmail-to-route-mail-to-specific-hosts-or-mailserver/
Sendmail full Monty minus mailertable
http://www.howtoforge.com/squirrelmail-configuration-easy-steps-squirrelmail-sendmail-apache-redhat-centos-fedora

If this doesn't work for you I'd recommend using installing webmin to configure the install. I would I highly recommend configure your firewall for outbound email.

Answer (score 0):

Never used them but they do have a free plan you can try out http://sendgrid.com/. My understanding is that it was specifically create to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. I need to be able to send lots of emails, since my site provides users with a mailing list system. The free plan wouldn't work and the non-free ones would cost far too much money.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are sending transactional emails, look at this [SMTP Relay Service](http://www.safentrix.com/outbound). No limit on emails that can be sent and Free option is available.